# Storing a string in a variable and using it is not working as expected

Tags: php, laravel

I am using alchemy api to filter out some data but here is something strange i face. I am storing a string in a variable and passing it to the alchemy api.

```
$dummytext = "Hello john Everything works here";

$file = $request->file('resume');
$extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
$contents = \File::get($file);

$parser = new Parser;
$pdf    = $parser->parseFile($file);

$text = $pdf->getText();
//echo $text;
$email_pattern = "/(?:[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|\"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?\.)+[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])/";

$user_email = preg_match_all($email_pattern, $text, $matches);

foreach ($matches as $match ) {                 
    foreach ($match as $email ) {
        $user_email = $email;
    }
}

$phone_pattern = '/[(]*\d{3}[)]*\s*[.\-\s]*\d{3}[.\-\s]*\d{4}/';

$user_phone = preg_match_all($phone_pattern, $text, $matches);
foreach ($matches as $match ) {
    foreach ($match as $phone) {

        $user_phone = $phone;
    }
}

echo "The user-email is : ".$user_email."<br>";
echo "The user-Phone is : ".$user_phone."<br>";

echo $text;
$response = $alchemyapi->entities('text',$dummytext, null);

if ($response['status'] == 'OK') {

    echo '## Entities ##', PHP_EOL."<br>";

    foreach ($response['entities'] as $entity) {

        if ($entity['type'] == "Person") {

                echo $entity['text'];
        }
    }
    echo PHP_EOL;
} 
else {
    echo 'Error in the taxonomy call: ', $response['statusInfo'];
}
```

In the above line when i `echo $text` it prints the text converted from the resume. The problem occurs is here

Here is where i pass the text to the alchemy api

```
$response = $alchemyapi->entities('text',$dummytext, null);
```

Here is something weird occurs. When i pass the `$dummytext` it works fine.
But when i pass `$text`

```
$response = $alchemyapi->entities('text',$text, null);
```

It returns nothing. Another issue is if i store the text i converted from the resume and pass to the api.

```
$resume_text = "This is text i received from the resume".
```

The below code works fine.

```
$response = $alchemyapi->entities('text',$resume_text, null);
```

But the `$text` variable is the same variable i used in `preg_match_all()` to extract email and phone. It works perfect there. I don't know what cause this issue.

Comment: have you tried to `var_dump` the `$text`  just before using it in : `$response = $alchemyapi->entities('text',$text, null); ` ? maybe its empty or not a string!

Comment: yes i did. It is not empty.

Comment: as you said its super weird ;).  maybe the output of  `getText()` function is an `array `  and not `string`

Comment: I did var_dump. It is string and not array